# breaking csv file in two files with python

Tags: python, csv

This is my first project using python and I'm not that great at programming. I have a csv file with two tables in it.

- table 1 title
- row1
- row2
- ...
- blank row
- blank row
- table 2 title
- row1
- row2
- ...

Here is my code

```
import csv

csv_file = open('usagebased.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)
```

So I want to split the file in two csv files. What is the best way to do it? Can i split the file based on title 2 or the blank rows?

Thanks!

Comment: can you fix your code format?

Comment: It sounds like you want to split the data out of 'usagebased.csv' into two files, without changing the row data in any way, apart from eliminating those blank lines. If so, there's no need to use the `csv` module, just read the file line by line, and copy the lines to the destination files. When you read an empty line continue looping until you see the new title line, close the old destination file and open the new one.

Comment: Why did you undo my edit that fixed your code formatting?

Comment: Ok thank you. This makes it a lot easier for me. In a few hours I will let you know if it worked out.

Comment: It was an accident, I'm new to the forum. I don't know how to put it back, I'm sorry...

Comment: No worries. I'll fix it again for you. The problem is that the code block got absorbed into the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `csv.reader` can accept any object that conforms the iterator protocol and outputs a string from `next()`. Knowing that, you can actually split you csv file in two lists by the blank rows. After that you can feed two `csv.reader` with both lists.

```
import csv

two_tables = open('usagebased.csv').read().split("\n\n\n")
# Feed first csv.reader
first_csv = csv.reader(two_tables[0], delimiter=',')
# Feed second csv.reader
second_csv = csv.reader(two_tables[1], delimiter=',')
```

Comment: That's certainly a fast and efficient way to do it. OTOH, if the input file is huge it will consume an awful lot of RAM, reading the whole thing into a string and then splitting it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you I succeeded. Thank you very much.

```
f = open('usagebased.csv').read().split("\n\n\n")
f1 = f[0]
f2 = f[1]

file1 = open('test1.csv','w')
file2 = open('test2.csv','w')

file1.write(f1)
file2.write(f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

in case that we don't know number of new lines , this can help
,i tried to write code as simple as possible :
since you don't do anything to csv things inside file you dont need to use csv library

```
FzListe
7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1, 7ZJB


7MA2, 7MA3, 7OS1
76G1, 7MA1, 7OS1
7MA1, 7OS1
71E5, 71E6, 7MA1, FSS1
```

here the code :

```
f= open('test.txt','rt')
while True:
 name = 0
 for s in f:
  if not s=='\n':
   with open(str(name),'at') as ff:
    ff.write(s)
  else:
   while s =='\n':
    s = next(f)
   name +=1
   with open(str(name),'at') as ff:
    ff.write(s)
```